# How to create transparent control with TCustomTransparentControl?

Tags: delphi

I want to create a transparent panel that holds an PNG image that has transparency in it. I want to put this panel on top of other panels and see trough.
I have the code below but it won't accept controls. If I uncomment the commented lines the IDE raises an exception when I put the controls on the form.

```
unit TransparentPanel5;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Vcl.Controls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TTransparentPanel5 = class(TCustomTransparentControl)
  private
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

constructor TTransparentPanel5.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  //ControlStyle := ControlStyle - [csSetCaption]+ [csAcceptsControls];
end;

procedure TTransparentPanel5.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
     inherited CreateParams(Params);
    // Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle + WS_EX_Transparent;
    // ControlStyle   := ControlStyle - [csOpaque] + [csAcceptsControls]
end;


procedure Register;
begin
     RegisterComponents('His', [TTransparentPanel5]);
end;

end.
```

Comment: You clearly need not set `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`, because `TCustomTransparentControl` does that for you.

Comment: Regarding "*it won't accept controls*" , I had to use the "structure pane" to move a control to have it parented by the transparent control. Probably because it doesn't have a *surface*, or something like it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got two unrelated questions. I chose to answer the second one.

The IDE raise an AV because you fail to apply extended styles properly. You have to use **or** operator to set a bit. When you use **+** you add up the value of the style bit and end up with an entirely different meaning, in this case with some `WS_EX_MDICHILD` which causes the `CreateWindowEx` call to fail.

Should be like this:

```
procedure TTransparentPanel5.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
     inherited CreateParams(Params);
     Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_Transparent;
    // ControlStyle   := ControlStyle - [csOpaque] + [csAcceptsControls]
end;
```

Note that it won't have any effect since the `TCustomTransparentControl` already sets that extended style.

Comment: I like your style ;-)

Comment: @David - Thanks. Actually I tested the first question and failed to reproduce.